# why variable declared to function without new keyword is undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunc(){
    this.taste = 'yummi';
    console.log(this.taste);
    console.log(typeof this);//logs object
}
var noNewObj = myFunc();
console.log(typeof noNewObj);//logs undefined
```

within the myFunc the `this` keyword refers to new object that is noNewObj but outside the function the variable noNewObj is declared to be a function without new keyword which is not an object, why?

Comment: myFunc does not puts anthing in noNewObj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`noNewObj` is assigned the *return value* of calling `myFunc()`, which is `undefined` as no explicit return value is given.

If you were trying to use `myFunc()` as a constructor, you need to use the `new` keyword, like so:

```
var noNewObj = new myFunc();
```

Also, if you do mean to use `myFunc()` as a constructor, you should start it with a capital letter, as that is a common Javascript convention to indicate that a function is a meant to be invoked with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

**No, it's wrong:** within the myFunc the this keyword refers to new object that is noNewObj

> If the new keyword is not used, then the 'this' variable inside the function will refer to the global object.

And there is no return value assigned so it logs undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`myFunc` does not puts/returns anthing in `noNewObj`,
  so it is undefined

```
function myFunc(){
    this.taste = 'yummi';
    console.log(this.taste);
    console.log(typeof this);//logs object
    //return something here
}
```